# how to include a page in WEB_INF from a different directory

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, include

[image: Folder Structure]

This is my folder Structure I want to include the page "common/tray.jsp" form "plan/add_edit.jsp" page

I have done `<!-- Tray -->
        <%@ include file="/common/tray.jsp" %>
        <!--  END Tray -->`
 in  plan/add_edit.jsp page But giving me

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /plan/add_edit.jsp (line: 47, column: 9) File "/plan/common/tray.jsp" not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ include file="../common/tray.jsp" %>
```